# is assign null to a variable enforce release memory or dispose varaible

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can anyone please tell me

1. What is the benefit of assigning `null` to variable after use ?
2. What is the meaning of assigning `null` after disposing a object ?
3. How does GC work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question 3 is very broad, and questions 1 and 2 aren't really specific enough to answer. Assigning the value null to a variable just does that...

Comment: @RahulTripathi Not quite true: Calling `Dispose()` should free unmanaged resources, but if you retain a non-null reference to a disposed object, the memory used for the object will still be in use. (Also, code might try to use the disposed object, with usually bad results. Making it null will at least cause a null reference exception if that happens.)

Answer (score 2):

1. When you assign `null` (C#) or `Nothing` (VB) to a variable, that removes that reference to the object previously assigned. Once there are no more references to an object, it becomes eligible for garbage collection, i.e. to have the memory it occupies returned to the system.
2. The same as 1.  Disposing the object releases any managed or unmanaged resources held by the object.  The memory occupied by that object is NOT considered a resource for these purposes.
3. There is far more to it than just this but the purpose of the GC is to return unused memory to the system for reallocation.  It can only reclaim the memory occupied by an object if there are no more managed references to that object, which is why nulling long-lived variables if you're no longer using the object is important.  A local variable would rarely be considered long-lived as it loses scope once the method completes.  A good example of a long-lived variable would be a field in the startup form of a WinForms application, which remains in scope for pretty much the entire lifetime of the app.
   It can also only reclaim the memory occupied by a disposable object if the object has been disposed.  That's why it's important to dispose an object once you're done with it if it supports disposal.  If you don't then the first time the GC tries to reclaim the memory that object occupies it will not be able to.  It will have to finalise the object first, which disposes it, and try again to reclaim the memory later.

Comment: Might also be worth stressing that it's not usually useful to set a local (stack) variable to null just to "free" it, since it will go out of scope when the method returns and be unrererenced anyway.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, true, which is why I did specify "long-lived variables". That could be a local but would rarely be, so you're probably right that making the distinction between local and member variables there would be useful.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - a local reference doesn't keep an object alive beyond the last time that the variable is read in the method. Objects can be cleaned up well before the end of a method that referenced them (at least in release mode).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Agreed, but that's just an implementation detail. The C# language specification only states that `if a local variable that is in scope is the only existing reference to an object, but that local variable is never referred to in any possible continuation of execution from the current execution point in the procedure, the garbage collector may *(but is not required to)* treat the object as no longer in use.`. (Of course, even when a method returns, any locals it used will still only become *eligible* for GC - there could be a delay before they're freed)

Comment: point 2 is not clear. I am working on a project where firstly dispose adapter and after that assign null value . what can i mean by it ?

Comment: My explanation of point 2 addresses your question.  Maybe you didn't ask the right question.  There are really just two simple rules that you need to follow in this regard.  1) If an object can be disposed then dispose it when you're finished using it.  2) If a variable refers to an object that you are finished using and that variable will not or may not lose scope or be reassigned for some time then null the variable.  If you follow those two rules then everything will work out.  You don't even need to understand why those things are good, only that they are good.